# verify length of checked inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I have a problem when I try to verify the number of checked inputs with appended content. It always alerts 0, instead of 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on how many I select.

The problem is from appended content because I tried with flat html, without appending content, and it's working.

Here is my script:

```
var $checks = $("body").on("change",".table",function () {
    if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<3)
    {
        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length>0);
        $checks.not(".ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
        alert($checks.filter(":checked").length);
    } else {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

And here is my append script, which runs on body load:

```
function local() {
    var id = getUrlParameter('id');
    var tip = getUrlParameter('tip');
    $.getJSON('http://rezerv.city/engine/app/local_mobil.php?tip='+ tip +'&id='+ id +'', function(data) {    
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.culoare == 'rosu')
            {
                var disable='disabled="disabled"';
                var ignore='ignore';
                var bg='background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg3_60.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;';
            } else {
                var disable='';
                var ignore='';
                var bg='background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg60.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;';
            }
            $(".plan_mese4").append('\
                <label class="masa_bg masa_bg_4 patru" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover" data-placement="bottom" style="margin-top:300px;margin-left:693px;'+ bg +'" data-original-title="" title="">\
                    <input class="table '+ ignore +'" type="checkbox" value="'+ val.mese +'" id="M'+ val.mese +'" name="masa[]" '+ disable +'><h4>'+ val.mese +'</h4><h5 class="nr_pers">'+ val.nr_pers +' persoane</h5>\
                </label>\'
            );
        });
    });
}
```

here is the html appended, as i said if i put flat html it's working, but when i append it inside a div doesnt not take the lenght

```
<label style="margin-top:370px;margin-left:780px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg_cerc.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click hover" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masa_bg masa_bg_4 patru" data-original-title="" title="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="masa[]" id="1C" value="342" class="table">
    <h4>1C</h4>
    <h5 class="nr_pers">10 persoane</h5>

</label>
<label style="margin-top:370px;margin-left:780px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg_cerc.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click hover" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masa_bg masa_bg_4 patru" data-original-title="" title="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="masa[]" id="1C" value="342" class="table">
    <h4>1C</h4>
    <h5 class="nr_pers">10 persoane</h5>

</label>
<label style="margin-top:370px;margin-left:780px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg_cerc.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click hover" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masa_bg masa_bg_4 patru" data-original-title="" title="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="masa[]" id="1C" value="342" class="table">
    <h4>1C</h4>
    <h5 class="nr_pers">10 persoane</h5>

</label>
<label style="margin-top:370px;margin-left:780px;background-image:url(http://rezerv.city/images/masa_bg_cerc.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="click hover" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masa_bg masa_bg_4 patru" data-original-title="" title="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="masa[]" id="1C" value="342" class="table">
    <h4>1C</h4>
    <h5 class="nr_pers">10 persoane</h5>

</label>
```

Comment: What's the relevant HTML?

Comment: Did you try to add the first script at the end of the second script? Also, you have many duplicated IDs, it's wrong, change it to classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suspect that the problem is the assignment of the `$checks` variable, which seems likely to run on page-load; which means that while you've used a jQuery method to catch events on dynamic content, you're still only using those elements present at page-load.

With this in mind, I'd suggest that instead of creating/initialising the `$checks` on page-load you should requery the DOM for the relevant elements when you run the function, giving:

```
$("body").on("change",".table",function () {
    var $checks = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    if ($checks.filter(":checked").length < 3) {

        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length > 0);
        $checks.not(".ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
        alert($checks.filter(":checked").length);
    } else {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

But this suggestion is, sadly, built on top of incomplete information given that we can't see your HTML or how the DOM is structured.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").on("change",".table",function () {
    var $checks = $(this).closest('div[class^="plan_mese"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<3)
    {
        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length>0);
        $checks.not(".ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
        alert($checks.filter(":checked").length);
    } else {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: this code now alert just 1 it doesnt matter how many inputs i check